# Let a,b,k,l ∈ Z. Suppose that ka+lb = 1. Prove that hcf(a,b) = 1.

Tags: number-theory

Please help! Been stuck on this for a while. I think I need to prove that all equations of the form ka+lb=c are multiples of the equation given by Bezout's lemma (ax+by=hcf(a,b)) and then use this to prove that hcf(a,b) is a factor of 1.

Comment: Hint. Suppose $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$. What can you conclude about $d$ given what you know? (You are overthinking this problem.)

Comment: I got it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier than you seem to think. If $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, then in particular, $d$ will divide both $ka$ and $lb$. From there the conclusion is immediate.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed.